# Intercepting Back Key in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I can't figure out how to handle below Activity Flow.

I have 2 activities and 1 view class in my android app.

Main Activity -> Sub Activity -> View Class  ( I am calling Sub Activity from Main Activity Class and with in Sub-Activity I am instantiating a View Class).

But When I press back button while in View Class it returns back to Main Activity.

View Class (Back Button Pressed) ->  Main Activity

But my desired behavior is like this :  View Class (Back Button Pressed) -> Sub-Activity -> Main Activity).

Please guide me how can I do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many activities are there? 2 or 3?

Comment: 2 activities.. Main and Sub Activity.. third one is View Class ( extending View)

Answer (score 3):

Activity has the `onBackPressed()` callback method. You can override this, but make sure to call `super.onBackPressed()` if you don't intend to act in a special way, so that the Activity can eventually back out normally.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (/* ... */) {
        // do something special
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to close view if Back key is pressed. How can I do it ?

Comment: It's your view and your code. Add some logic to determine if the view is "open" -- it can either be part of the view itself or the Activity can keep track of it. That will be the condition for the `if` statement. Inside, you can do whatever you need to "close" the view.

Answer (score 1):

ok , you can listen the key event in sub activity. like this:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK&&your view is not close) {
            closeyourview();
            return true;// important you can close your view here
        }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: How to check if View is closed or not ?

Comment: You can put the logic in your own view, such as put a member variable to record; or try this: View.getVisibility() to judge status

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by View Class. Maybe you can use a new activity to show the view, then everything will be OK.

Comment: View class means ->   someCustomImageLoad extends View { }. When I call it from my sub-activity then it covers whole screen and user can zoom in or out a bitmap.

Comment: If it takes the whole screen, why not get a new activity for that?